# How do I get the Sand Hawk SMG?

Tags: borderlands-2

On Borderlands 2, what quest gives the Sand Hawk? And if so, do I need any DLC to get the mission, if it is given by a mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the Wiki.

> The Sand Hawk is a Unique Submachine Gun manufactured by Dahl, added
>   in the DLC expansion **Captain Scarlett and Her Pirate's Booty**. Sand
>   Hawk is obtained from the mission **Whoops** located in Wurmwater.

The Wiki itself is pretty well kept and it is worth trying that first for similar questions to this.

Source: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sand_Hawk